Catalog of integral symmetric lattices
Let $g$ be an integral symmetric matrix (perhaps with even diagonal components), and define an equivalence relation $g\sim g'$ if $g=UgU^T$ with $U$ a unimodular integral matrix.
For fixed $\det g$ (and size), there are finitely many equivalence classes. I am looking for a catalog of representatives for all classes, for small values of $\det g$. In a previous laptop I had a bookmark of a webpage with precisely this, but now I cannot find it anymore. Any help is appreciated.

http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/

@WillJagy Thanks. Any idea how to navigate this webpage? Where are the matrices I am looking for?

Pick an individual lattice, there will often be a Gram matrix http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/D3.html   ;;;;;;;;;; http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/D3.html#GRAM

@WillJagy Thanks again. In dimension-2 I only see four lattices A2, A2*, D2, D2*. Which have det = 2,2,3,1/4. Surely this is not the full list of 2d integral matrices, right? The last one is not even integral. Where are the rest?

I guess they   emphasize "interesting" lattices. Try dimension 3,    Alexander's table  http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/Brandt_2.html   and read his introduction. Your matrices are given as a sextuple of integers  in one line, as  1: 1 1 1 1 1 1   or 2: 1 1 1 0 0 1 ... Note that the initial number 1: or 2: is just an index number for the computer list, it has no mathematical meaning  The Gram matrix is then   [ 2a1   a6   a5 ] ///
[ a6   2a2   a4 ] ///
[ a5   a4   2a3 ],///

Nipp provided similar tables for dimensions 4,5.

@WillJagy Oh, I definitely want the "non-interesting" lattices too. I don't think there is anything special about the lattices they list, as opposed to all the rest.
